# Derived textbox doesn't show IDataError tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I have created an own textbox which inherits from TextBox.

But there isn't any tooltip displayed if IDataError returns an error message...

```
<customTextBox:LetterOnlyTextbox
Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"/>
```

What do I wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show your `ErrorTemplate`?

Answer (score -1):

sorry for my thread... I have found the error on my own:

I have to set the Tooltip property for my custom control. I thought this would be done for me by creating a style for targettype TextBox.